# Smo Scripter scripting user script with "Incorrect Syntax"

Tags: c#, sql, smo

I am using Smo to script a db's users and their roles.  Here is how I am doing it:

```
var scripter = new Scripter(server)
{
    Options = new ScriptingOptions()
    {
        IncludeIfNotExists = true,
        IncludeDatabaseRoleMemberships = true,
        // lots of other options here
    }
};

foreach (User smoObject in database.Users)
{
    var sc = scripter.Script(new Urn[] { smoObject.Urn });
    // write to file here
}
```

The result is something like this:

```
/****** Object:  User [myuser]    Script Date: 12/10/2013 5:00:57 PM ******/
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.database_principals WHERE name = N'myuser')
CREATE USER [myuser] WITHOUT LOGIN WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=[dbo]
sys.sp_addrolemember @rolename = N'r_execprocs', @membername = N'myuser'
sys.sp_addrolemember @rolename = N'db_owner', @membername = N'myuser'
sys.sp_addrolemember @rolename = N'db_datareader', @membername = N'myuser'
sys.sp_addrolemember @rolename = N'db_datawriter', @membername = N'myuser'
```

But if you were to try and run this script against the database you would get:

"Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
Incorrect syntax near 'sys'."

If, however, I manually change the script to be:

```
/****** Object:  User [myuser]    Script Date: 12/10/2013 5:00:57 PM ******/
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.database_principals WHERE name = N'myuser')
CREATE USER [myuser] WITHOUT LOGIN WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=[dbo]
GO
sys.sp_addrolemember @rolename = N'r_execprocs', @membername = N'myuser'
GO
sys.sp_addrolemember @rolename = N'db_owner', @membername = N'myuser'
GO
sys.sp_addrolemember @rolename = N'db_datareader', @membername = N'myuser'
GO
sys.sp_addrolemember @rolename = N'db_datawriter', @membername = N'myuser'
GO
```

The script works perfectly.  Is there a way to either:

- run the script as is without getting "Incorrect Syntax" or
- make the scripter generate this script in a way that is runnable
  ?

Comment: Stored procedure calls that aren't the first command in a batch need to be preceded by `EXEC`.  You can either add `EXEC` before each call to `sys.sp_addrolememeber`, or put each command into its own batch by using `GO` like you've shown here.

Comment: Is there a way to have that generated using the Smo library?

Comment: @saml  user.AddToRole("db_datareader"); etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, figured it out.  The scripter can do any combination of 2 things:

- output the script to an in memory `StringCollection`
- output the script to a file determined by `scripter.Options.FileName`

When scripting to a string collection, for some reason it does not script batch terminator `GO` between sp calls, however it does when scripting to a file.  So I changed the above code to look like this:

```
var scripter = new Scripter(server)
{
    Options = new ScriptingOptions()
    {
        IncludeIfNotExists = true,
        IncludeDatabaseRoleMemberships = true,

        //ADDED THIS OPTION
        FileName = Path.Combine(path, "Script.sql"),

        // lots of other options here
    }
};

foreach (User smoObject in database.Users)
{
    var sc = scripter.Script(new Urn[] { smoObject.Urn });
    // no need to write to file anymore since scripter automatically does it
}
```

The result was:

```
/****** Object:  User [myuser]    Script Date: 12/10/2013 5:00:57 PM ******/
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.database_principals WHERE name = N'myuser')
CREATE USER [myuser] WITHOUT LOGIN WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=[dbo]
GO
sys.sp_addrolemember @rolename = N'r_execprocs', @membername = N'myuser'
GO
sys.sp_addrolemember @rolename = N'db_owner', @membername = N'myuser'
GO
sys.sp_addrolemember @rolename = N'db_datareader', @membername = N'myuser'
GO
sys.sp_addrolemember @rolename = N'db_datawriter', @membername = N'myuser'
GO
```